# Target table names are not same as source table name while importing csv files into postgresql using Dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, dbeaver

I am importing csv files into my postgreSQL server through DBeaver. My csv file name are same except the ending part as they have different year values such as "apr_apr_2011" and "apr_apr_2012" (i have hundreds of files having this name pattern). Now, when I am importing these files the numeric part at end is being trimmed by the dbeaver as:
[image: Target table names are different than source table names especially the numeric part is trimmed]

Therefore, Dbeaver is importing only first table and  then gives the relation already exist error:
[image: Error]

As I need to import hundred of tables, can I avoid this error in Dbeaver?